# How to assign labels to samples produced in ImageDataGenerator

Tags: python, keras, classification, conv-neural-network

I'm new to Convolutional Neural Networks and I'm about to build my first ConvNet which is a multi-class image classification ConvNet.

**Model Description**

Let's say I have two image folders, one contains few thousands of images of a particular type of leaves (Leaves A) (Image set X) and other folder contain same number of images of similar type of leaves (Leaves B) (Image set Y). So I need to train my model to distinguish those two types.

**Problem Background**

Since I have two classes of outputs Leaves A and Leaves B, I have either 0,1 as an output or 1,0 as an output for a given image of Leaves A class or Leaves B class.

```
                            Leaves A | Leaves B
If Input is a Class A Leaf,     1         0
If Input is a Class B Leaf,     0         1
```

**Problem**

So in order to do that, I have to label my image set X to have output 1,0 and image set Y to have output 0,1. Also since I need to augment images to have more training samples, I used ImageDataGenerator.

```
training_imGen.flow_from_directory(
                                'path/to/image_folder_X',
                                target_size=(1100,180),
                                batch_size=batchSize,
                                color_mode='rgb',
                                class_mode='categorical'
                                )
```

But here I cannot assign a label. Not like when I use `training_imGen.flow`. However I found `classes` parameter can be called under flow_from_directory,

`classes: optional list of class subdirectories (e.g. ['dogs', 'cats']). Default: None. If not provided, the list of classes will be automatically inferred from the subdirectory names/structure under directory, where each subdirectory will be treated as a different class (and the order of the classes, which will map to the label indices, will be alphanumeric).`

But I don't know how to specify two class labels there since I only give the path to `image set X` folder. Any ideas how to do that?

**Update**

```
training_imGen.flow_from_directory(
                                '/Users/user/database/',
                                target_size=(1100,180),                                                 
                                batch_size=batchSize,
                                color_mode='rgb',
                                class_mode='categorical',
                                classes=['Set_A', 'Set_B']
                                )
```

Under `/Users/user/database/` path, there are two folders called `Set_A` and `Set_B`. As I have mentioned each folder contains related png image files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out how [DirectoryIterator](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/preprocessing/image.py#L1313) is implemented. It's a very simple class.

`ImageDataGenerator#flow_from_directory` is just a wrapper to a `DirectoryIterator` object construction. You don't have to manually specify the labels because `DirectoryIterator` will automatically assume that each sample is associated with a class named after that sample's parent folder.
So, as long as all samples of leaves `A` are inside the same folder named `A` and samples of leaves `B` are inside a different folder, they will be correctly assigned to their respective classes.

Furthermore, the iterator's output will already be one-hot encoded, as you defined `class_mode` as `categorical`:

```py
g = ImageDataGenerator()
train = g.flow_from_directory('/path/to/dataset/train/',
                              batch_size=32,
                              target_size=(1100, 180))

x_batch, y_batch = next(train)
assert x_batch.shape == (32, 1100, 180, 3) 
assert y_batch.shape == (32, 2)
print(y_batch)
[[0. 1.],
 [1. 0.],
 [1. 0.],
 ...
 [0. 1.]]
```

The `classes` parameter is not used to set the labels of each sample, but instead to specify a list of sub-folders of `directory` that should be considered as classes by that iterator (e.g. `['A', 'B']`). If the default `None` is kept, then all sub-folders of `directory` are considered valid classes, and all images inside them are potential samples for the set. This is useful when you only want to work with a subset of labels, debug your code or hold-off classes.

If you wish to override the default labeling, then you can simply replace the content in `DirectoryIterator#classes`, which contains the class associated with the `ith` sample at its `ith` element. For example, let's say you want to add a third class of leaves which doesn't have an associated folder:

```py
train = g.flow_from_directory(...)
train.classes = np.asarray([0., 1., 2., ..., 0., 1.])
train.class_indices = {'A': 0, 'B': 1, 'C': 2}
train.num_classes = 3
```

Comment: Thank you. One simple question. If I kept my folder `image_set_X` and `image_set_Y` under `'/path/to/dataset/train/'`, it will automatically get `image_set_X` and `image_set_Y` as class names?

Comment: Each sample will be associated with either the class `0.` or `1.` and `it.class_indices` will be `{'image_set_X': 0., 'image_set_Y': 1.}`. So you can use these two properties to reconstruct the sample-class name relationship.

Comment: I thought not to override the class, but instead keep as it usually do the thing. So I updated my code as I mentioned in Update section above. But when I run the code, it shows `Found 0 images belonging to 2 classes.`

Comment: Make sure you have image files inside `{directory}/image_set_X` and `{directory}/image_set_Y` and that they are saved in one of the following white-listed formats: `'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'bmp', 'ppm', 'tif', 'tiff'`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Simple parameter name caused the problem. Thank you again.